# Oracle csv line size more than 32767

Tags: oracle, linux, scripting

How to generate csv in oracle if it's query result return more than 32767 character per line  in linux shell script

Comment: From SQL*Plus, or something else?

Comment: What problem are you actually having?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use utl_file, since it has a maximum line length of 32767.
It's possible that sqlplus has a similar limit. If you are tying to 
move data to a different Oracle database you can use data pump. You 
can eve use datapump on a materialized view. If you want to migrate 
to a non Oracle database you can use Perl or heterogeneous services
to create a database connection to mySQL, SQL Server, etc. Then you
won't have to worry about the line length.

[UTL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1005018)

Comment: You could however populate a clob with all your data, appending a new line character after each row then use utl_file to write to file by reading from clob. If you open the file with utl_file.fopen(..., max_linesize=>32767); you can write upto 32767 characters in each write. if you want to enter more characters per line, use utl_file.put multiple times, at the end add a new line character. lather. rinse. repeat for next line.

Comment: The clob can work, if you use dbms_lob to write to a file on disk.

Comment: are you saying that there is a dependency here? i.e. clob can work if used with dbms_lob? i am fairly certain you can write clob contents using utl_file too.

Comment: No, I am not saying that there is a dependency. I am saying that if you take a clob and write it to a file as a clob, then you will have fewer restrictions on how large the clob can be. It would likely be more efficient to use dbms_lob as well. But i have not proven that dbms_lob will work in this case. The OP should try to code a solution using clob and dbms_lob to see if it can handle linesize larger than 32k.